# How to track/find out which userdata are GC-ed at certain time?

Tags: luajit

I've written an app in LuaJIT, using a third-party GUI framework (FFI-based) + some additional custom FFI calls. The app suddenly loses part of its functionality at some point soon after being run, and I'm quite confident it's because of some unpinned objects being GC-ed. I assume they're **only referenced from the C world<sup>1</sup>, so Lua GC thinks they're unreferenced** and can free them. The problem is, I don't know *which* of the numerous userdata are unreferenced (unpinned) on Lua side?

To confirm my theory, I've run the app with GC disabled, via:

```lua
collectgarbage 'stop'
```

and lo, with this line, the app works perfectly well *long* past the point where it got broken before. Obviously, it's an ugly workaround, and I'd much prefer to have the GC enabled, and the app still working correctly...

I want to find out which unpinned object (userdata, I assume) gets GCed, so I can pin it properly on Lua side, to prevent it being GCed prematurely. Thus, my question is:

***(How) can I track which userdata objects got collected when my app loses functionality?***

One problem is, that AFAIK, the LuaJIT FFI already assigns custom `__gc` handlers, so I cannot add my own, as there can be only one per object. And anyway, the framework is too big for me to try adding `__gc` in each and every imaginable place in it. Also, I've already eliminated the "most obviously suspected" places in the code, by removing `local` from some variables — thus making them part of `_G`, so I assume not GC-able. (Or is that not enough?)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Specifically, WinAPI.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've added some [ffi.gc()](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html#ffi_gc) handlers to some of my objects (printing some easily visible ALL-CAPS messages), then added some eager [collectgarbage()](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage) calls to try triggering the issue as soon as possible:

```
ffi.gc(foo, function()
    print '\n\nGC FOO !!!\n\n'
end)

[...]

collectgarbage()
```

And indeed, this exposed some GCing I didn't expect. Specifically, it led me to discover [a note in luajit's FFI docs](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#gc), which is most certainly relevant in my case:

> Please note that [C] pointers [...] are **not** followed by the garbage collector. So e.g. if you assign a cdata array to a pointer, you must keep the cdata object holding the array alive [in Lua] as long as the pointer is still in use.